# "Problems" window shows fake errors

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Eclipse CDT is showing strange errors in my editor/problems windows. For example, for a line like:

```
#include <string>
```

it says: `Unresolved inclusion: <string>`, as if Eclipse couldn't find such a basic include file. Of course because of those include errors, almost no definition is recognized later, resulting in even more errors. This is despite that the project builds correctly from Eclipse.

This is an `autotools`-based source. The project was set to custom Makefile mode. I use Debian, Eclipse 3.7.

How to get rid of those fake errors?

Comment: Try deleting the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen eclipse have issues like this occasionally in the past. For me, it was a project with a few header files, but no actual compile-able items. It would correctly detect errors when building projects that referenced it, but would fail to get rid of the errors once they were fixed.

You can start by deleting the particular errors/warnings manually in the problem window and see if they stay away.

Comment: I actually restarted Eclipse several times and rebuilt the project several times and after that it somehow started to work...